# Выполнить операцию в отдельном потоке

Tags: php, многопоточность, php-fpm

Есть сайт, работает на PHP 7.3 + PHP-FPM. Необходимо отправлять push уведомления при определенных событиях, которые происходят при взаимодействиях с сайтом. Мне бы не хотелось, чтобы отправка пушей задерживала время ответа. Возможно ли отправить эти пуши без боли просто в другом потоке примерно как-то так:
new Thread()-> run(function(){ sendPush! });

Без отдельных воркеров, очередей. Или на php-fpm это не возможно и нужен асинхронный веб сервер?

Comment: А вы точно выбрали правильный язык для реализации своих идей?

Comment: Да, точно, язык более чем подходит. Это единственная задача, с которой возникают трудности. Просто не хотелось бы зависеть от времени ответа какого-то внешнего сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таких возможностей в PHP нет. Можно сделать Sheduler, который по крону проверяет наличие актуальных задач и будет отправлять push уведомления, либо отдельный сервис-демон, желательно не на PHP (но если хочется можно и на нем), который будет через Redis, а еще лучше через RabbitMQ принимать задачи. В конечно итоге это пригодится, как воркер выполняющий отложенные задачи, или задачи, которые не нужно выполнять в главном потоке. А сам сайт так и останется на PHP без необходимости отказываться от CMS (будь то Wordpress, или CS-Cart).